# What is best practice when linking to several similar sources in a rails view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller, environment-variables

I'm working on a microservices framework in rails, and have come across a View in which we want to link out to several different applications that will reference the `user` being displayed. The `user` is identified through a `user-urn`.

Some notes about the applications we're linking to --

- Every different application has a unique url
- Not every application references the `user` through the same route -- i.e. meaning we can have `/users/user-urn`, or `/users?urn=user-urn`
- We'd like to be able to configure the external applications url for testing purposes.

My first instinct was to add a link helper, that would take the arguments of a `user` (given from the view), generate the `link_to` strategy with the url stored as an `ENV`. It looked like this --

`def app_1_link(user)
    url = "#{ENV['APP_1_URL']}/users/#{user.urn}"
    link_to "Application 1", url, :target => "_blank"
 end`

This made the helper too large, seeing that we needed many different helpers to accomplish the same goal.

My questions is -- is it bad practice to just add all of these links directly into the view with `ENV` vars?

e.g. (`<p><%= link_to "App 1", "#{ENV['APP_1_URL']}/users/#{@user.urn}", :target => "_blank" %> </p>`

Or should I build out some additional class/module logic to properly handle building the links?

Answer (score 0):

I would make a db table to hold the information for the different applications, and a corresponding model.  Once you start having big lists of stuff in your config files, stored as constants, it's usually a sign that you should move it over into the database.

Then, you can have a model method in your ExternalApp model (or whatever you call it) to generate the necessary url.